# FB.ui returns Error: element not specified

Tags: facebook, jquery-mobile, facebook-javascript-sdk

Using [the example from the developer site:](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/)

```
FB.ui(
  {
    method: 'feed',
    name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
    link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
    picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
    caption: 'Reference Documentation',
    description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.'
  },
  function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
      alert('Post was published.');
    } else {
      alert('Post was not published.');
    }
  }
);
```

I get the following back:

```
Error: element not specified
innerError: undefined
message: "element not specified"
```

At first I thought I was missing the "fb-root" element, but I have it in my body:

```
<body onLoad="onLoad()">
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
</body>
```

Now I'm thinking it has something to do with my Backbone/jQuery Mobile usage, because the body is cleared once the first page is loaded. However, the `FB` object is loaded, so I really don't know what's wrong. Any ideas to try and fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: tell me you are not doing this with onLoad() functions?

Comment: Are you actually including the SDK?

Comment: no, this is well after onLoad(). i load the sdk in a js file in my `<head>`, as well as set up `window.fbAsyncInit`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I figured out that was happening just with Chrome. Which browser are you using?
What worked for me was specifying

```
display: 'popup'
```

inside FB.ui {}

At the moment I check the browser and if Chrome I use 'popup', if not 'iframe'

```
  var display = 'iframe';

  if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("chrome") != -1){
          display = "popup"
  }

  FB.ui({
        method: 'share',
        display: display,
        href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/'
        },
   function (response) {}
  );
```

Should work also with feed, but I haven't tested it yet.